# CSS: Center text/svg in display inline-block

Tags: html, css, svg

I have certain inline-block elements. and in that I have svg which I want to be in the center of div (vertically as well as horizontally)

I have tried below code.

```css
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div svg {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-purple {
  background: purple;
}

.v-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme_color_selection_main_div m-t-md text-center">
  <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-blue">
    <div class="text-center">
      <svg class="v-middle" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                            <path d="m.3,14c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.7s0.1-0.5 0.3-0.7l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l.1,.1 5.5,5.9c0.2,0.2 0.5,0.2 0.7,0l13.4-13.9h0.1v-8.88178e-16c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4 0.4,1 0,1.4l0,0-16,16.6c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-7.8-8.4-.2-.3z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                          </svg>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-purple">

  </div>
  <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-red">

  </div>

</div>
```

I want svg to be center.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of centering the svg, try to center its div container. You can do it by adding this `.svg-container` class with the following rules:

```
.svg-container{
      width: 10px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The only constraint here is the width of the div, which has to be like that on the svg which is fixed already, so this should not be an issue. Below is a working snippet.

```css
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div svg {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-red {
  background: red;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-purple {
  background: purple;
}

.v-middle{
vertical-align:middle;
}

.svg-container{
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="theme_color_selection_main_div m-t-md text-center">
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-blue">
      <div class="svg-container">
        <svg class="v-middle" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26"  version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
        <path d="m.3,14c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.7s0.1-0.5 0.3-0.7l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l.1,.1 5.5,5.9c0.2,0.2 0.5,0.2 0.7,0l13.4-13.9h0.1v-8.88178e-16c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4 0.4,1 0,1.4l0,0-16,16.6c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-7.8-8.4-.2-.3z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-purple">
    </div>
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-red">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` for this, check updated snippet below:

```css
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div svg {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-red {
  background: red;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-purple {
  background: purple;
}
.v-middle{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme_color_selection_main_div m-t-md text-center">
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-blue">
        <svg class="v-middle" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
            <path d="m.3,14c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.7s0.1-0.5 0.3-0.7l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l.1,.1 5.5,5.9c0.2,0.2 0.5,0.2 0.7,0l13.4-13.9h0.1v-8.88178e-16c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4 0.4,1 0,1.4l0,0-16,16.6c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-7.8-8.4-.2-.3z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-purple">
    </div>
    <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-red">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as your elements are fixed width and height, you can simply set `position: relative` to the parent and

```
position: absolute;
top: 7.5px;
left: 7.5px;
```

to the child (svg element)

```css
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  position: relative;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div svg {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5px;
  left: 7.5px;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-blue {
  background: blue;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-red {
  background: red;
}
.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-purple {
  background: purple;
}

.v-middle{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme_color_selection_main_div m-t-md text-center">
                        <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-blue">
                          <div class="text-center">
                            <svg class="v-middle" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26"  version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                            <path d="m.3,14c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.7s0.1-0.5 0.3-0.7l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l.1,.1 5.5,5.9c0.2,0.2 0.5,0.2 0.7,0l13.4-13.9h0.1v-8.88178e-16c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4 0.4,1 0,1.4l0,0-16,16.6c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-7.8-8.4-.2-.3z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                          </svg>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-purple">

                        </div>
                        <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-red">

                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using `position:absolute` plus `transform:translate`

```css
.text-center {}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .theme_color_selection_inner_div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.theme_color_selection_main_div .bg-blue {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.v-middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme_color_selection_main_div m-t-md text-center">
  <div class="theme_color_selection_inner_div bg-blue">
    <div class="text-center">
      <svg class="v-middle" enable-background="new 0 0 26 26" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                            <path d="m.3,14c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.7s0.1-0.5 0.3-0.7l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l.1,.1 5.5,5.9c0.2,0.2 0.5,0.2 0.7,0l13.4-13.9h0.1v-8.88178e-16c0.4-0.4 1-0.4 1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4 0.4,1 0,1.4l0,0-16,16.6c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.3-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-7.8-8.4-.2-.3z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                          </svg>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```